# Is it possible to create a parabola by intersecting a hyperboloid of one sheet and a plane?

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, 3d

By which I mean, is there anyway that the intersetion of a plane and a hyperboloid of one sheet will be a parabola?

I know that intersecting a plane and a cone so that the plane is parallel to the edge of the cone will result in a parabola, but is there any way to do something similar with a hyperboloid of one sheet?

I am a little confused because I thought a hyperbola extended in a straight line as it goes to infinity (kind of like the graph of $y^2=x^2$), so I thought that a hyperboloid of one sheet would act like a cone (in that the edge is a straight line that heads to infinity).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try $x^2+y^2-z^2=-1$, $z>0$ (one component of a two sheeted hyperboloid) or $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$ intersected with $x= z-1$.

Comment: That's (half of) a hyperboloid of two sheets.

Comment: I see. I interpreted the question as one connected component... I added both cases.

Comment: Thanks! Follow up question -- since it is possible to get a parabola by intersecting a hyperboloid of one sheet and a plane, does this mean it is safe to say that a 2D hyperbola behaves like $y^2=x^2$ except around the origin?

Comment: @TimDrake In mathematics you have to be more specific than that. Just say explicitly what you mean by "behaves like".

Comment: @WimC I suppose I mean, as x approaches infinity on a hyperbola, does it approach the graph of $y^2=x^2$?

Comment: @downvoter: care to indicate what’s wrong and how to improve this answer?